# CHMOD files (Set Permission) after uploading on Local Server Windows XP

Tags: php, upload, windows-xp, chmod

I have a local webserver on Windows XP

using this code:

```
  if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $dstPath)){
  @chmod($dstPath, 0755);
  echo "Upload Complete!";
```

and nothing happens to the uploaded file!

I have an upload script made by someone
and when I upload an image CHMOD function work!

Why then with my 'simple script' it doesn't ?

Comment: Why don't you remove the `@` and find out?

Comment: In fact I removed it, but did not change anything!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with the script but where you use it. Sadly, it's not written on the [documentation](http://fr.php.net/CHMOD) but `chmod` is intended to be use on *nix server/computers.

The file permissions model on Windows is different and mainly based on ACL.

Comment: ok why its worked with another script ? I think it the same command also!

Comment: Why not ask why your standard stick shift car is stalling, when just pushing on the gas worked fine on the automatic. Unix and Windows are two completely different platforms, and chmod (being from the Unix side) can't be expected to work on Windows the same way.

Comment: @Swell: I think `chmod` is working, just on windows it won't do anything. Plus in your case apart if you got a weird setup with your webserver user being a different user that the one who run the php scripts you won't need to chmod files. If your file upload is not working I would guess it would be because you forgot to set the `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to your form.

Comment: @Marc B: I know that Unix and Windows are two completely different platforms !
@RageZ: Thank you but i'm useing "Local Server", and its work fine i can upload and open the file after uploading my problem not this my problem is to set the permission! thx anyway

Comment: @Swell: Why do you need to set the permissions on those files?

Comment: Actually I don't know why ? I am currently programming an images upload script, so i think i should to set permissions to UploadDIR and the images inside this DIR, Am I right?

Comment: @Swell: you should make sure the upload dir is writable by your webserver. You can do that by checking the property of the directory in windows explorer. Concerning the files you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @RageZ: Thank you, what should id do with this question , should i delete it ?

Comment: @Swell: let it be, and if you wanna be nice to me accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can not because as i said before CHMOD worked on windows with the script which i mention, so maybe there is a solution  someway. thx

Comment: [How about this.](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php#72419) Haven't tested it myself, TBH :)